# Retrieving Records From one record to another record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In database I have 14000 thousand records, in c# with entity framework, I am retrieving that data I am using this record,

```
var Db = new SD_HolidayTaxiEntities();
var records = Db.sp_uniquerecords().ToList().Take(1000);
```

but it will be give 1 t0 1000 I want again 1001 to 2000 then 2001 to 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `Skip` method:

```
Db.sp_uniquerecords().Skip(1000).Take(1000).ToList();
```